# Codeigniter redirection without using .htaccess

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect

I am trying to redirect all the links that leads to a page in Spanish to another page in English
so if the link is www.mysite.com/sp/show/page/welcome
i want it to go to www.mysite.com/en/show/page/welcome

is it possible to do it using the index.php file ? since .htaccess doesn't work for me.

Regards.

Comment: Why `.htaccess` doesn't work?

Comment: Can't you use route configuration?

Answer (score 0):

What if you put this at the beginning of each Spanish file:

```
$english = str_replace("/sp/", "/en/", getcwd());
header("Location: ". $spannish. "/");
```